# Call to undefined function create_function() - PHP 8.2

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

My wordress plugin is giving some issue. I am using 8.2 PHP version but the plugin is very old.

```
define('BBP_BBCODE_PATH', WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/plugins/'.plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__)) );

//Admin options
include(BBP_BBCODE_PATH.'/bbpress2-bbcode-admin.php');

//Classes
include(BBP_BBCODE_PATH.'/class_bbpress2-bbcode.php');

// Start this plugin once all other plugins are fully loaded
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', create_function( '', 'global $BBCode; $BBCode = new BBCode();' ) );
?>
```

The problem is with this code - `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', create_function( '', 'global $BBCode; $BBCode = new BBCode();' ) );`

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue

Comment: `create_function` was removed from PHP back in 8.0, 3 years ago. This plugin is effectively dead in the water.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to edit this line:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', create_function( '', 'global $BBCode; $BBCode = new BBCode();' ) );
```

You will want to make yourself an actual function. Probably something like this:

```
function my_hacked_function(){
    global $BBCode; 
    $BBCode = new BBCode();
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my_hacked_function');
```

I've not tested this. However, this is the general direction you will want to go.